# How to store iteration array into one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array code like shown below, the result is a 2x2 array.

How to change it so that every iteration stores to a single `new_A` array (instead of 3 arrays)?

```
A = np. array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
a = A.shape[0]
new_A = []
for i in range(1, a+2):
     B =mp( A, i)
     new_A += [B]
print(new_A)
```

**Here's the result:**

```
 [array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]), array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]]), array([[ 37,  54],
       [ 81, 118]])]
```

Comment: what language? Python? 3? Give more information about your context.

Comment: What is `mp` ? a function ?

Answer (score 0):

You actually  only have **one new_A**.
What is happened is that you mp function returns a array, so you are **inserting 3 new arrays inside your new_A**. But you only have one new_A array.
Maybe what you want is that your mp function return a scalar value and not a array.